# Can't repeat negated pattern using \@!

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I have this text:

````
```python
x = 1
```
````

Basically markdown python cells. I would like to extract the content of the cell surrounding the cursor, if any.

As you may have guessed already, I am trying to build a jupyter workflow, I use [jupytex](https://github.com/goerz/jupytext.vim) and vim-slime for the console, and I would like to send cells to the console.

Currently I am struggling just matching a cell with regex:

````
/```python\(\(```\)\@!\)*```
````

This should match a string starting with ```python, then everything except triple quotes, then triple quotes, but it doesn't.

Strangely, this one(without the ending triple quotes:

````
/```python\(\(```\)\@!\)*
````

highlights ```python, but nothing more.

So what would be a regex to match a python cell? Bonus for a regex that matches the content of the cell under cursor!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This should match a string starting with ```python, then everything except triple quotes, then triple quotes, but it doesn't.

That's because the `*` multi does not repeat any character; it just repeats a negative lookahead, which doesn't add anything to the overall match.  The regex engine can't reach the closing triple backticks.

````
/```python\(\(```\)\@!\)*```
            ^--------^
                ✘
````

Add a character inside:

````
/```python\(\(```\)\@!\_.\)*```
                      ^-^
````

Note that `\_.` can match any character, including a newline; contrary to `.` which can't match a newline.  See [`:h /\_`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/_.).

---

> So what would be a regex to match a python cell? Bonus for a regex that matches the content of the cell under cursor!

Try this:

````
```python\n\%(\%(```\)\@!\_.\)*\%#\_.\{-}\n```\n
                               ├─┘   ├──┘
                               │     └ as few as possible
                               └ the cursor position must match here
````

See [`:h /\%#`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#cursor-position), and [`:h /\{-`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/%7B-).

Comment: I've checked against your sample file, and it works.  Note that your cursor needs to be inside a python cell for a match to be found.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you.

Comment: And for only selecting the content of the cell: `/\(\```python\n\)\@<=\%(\%(```\)\@!\_.\)*\%#\_.\{-}\(\```\)\@= `

Comment: @NickSkywalker The vim help recommends using `\zs` and `\ze` instead of lookarounds when possible, for performance reasons. In this instance, they result in a slightly simpler regular expression, too, as you can dispense with some of the capture groups: ``/```python\n\zs\%(\%(```\)\@!\_.\)*\%#\_.\{-}\ze``` ``

Comment: Thank you, I was sure there was something like this, that's a lot better :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand those advanced regexes, but this one should do:

````
^```python\_$\_.\{-}\_^```$
````

To understand it, let `:help ordinary_atom` guide us:

- `\_$` matches end-of-line.
- `\_.` matches any character, including end-of-lines.
- `\_^` matches start-of-line.

And with `:help non-greedy`,

- `\{-}` is the same as `*` but uses the shortest match first algorithm.
  Remember that it applies only to the previous element, `\_.` in our case.

You may want to relax the regex a bit, maybe removing the `^` and `$` anchoring.

Tested in this sample, the regex matches only the python cells.

````
This is Python:
```python
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```
This is FORTRAN:
```fortran
DO I=1,10
    WRITE(*,*)I
ENDDO
```
This is Python again
```python
for i in range(10):
print('```')
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) While this work the second answer matches better the question.